# Fix positioned menu bar covers elements that's linked to it

Tags: html, css, fixed, menubar

I'm working on a static one paged website which has a fix positioned menu bar on the top. When I hit the links on the menu bar it goes down to the linked element and it covers it.

Here is a snippet from my html and css:
[Here is the fiddle fo shizzle my nizzles](http://jsfiddle.net/hPh6D/)

```
nav {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    width:70%;
    position:fixed;
       ...
}
```

How can I make it to act like a normal menu bar and not cover the linked elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced a similer prob where i've used some jquery.

```
$('#linkId').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#toMove').offset().top });

});
```

but now in your case since the header is a fixed one i've done something and updated the same here in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/hPh6D/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
I prefer your way to solve it but i don't know javascript.
What is the second row's "$('html, body')..." for?

Comment: i does mean like moving the whole body of the html. BTW you may have checked my answer if you have used my answer :P

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add padding-top to the element **after** the fixed div to push it down.

[**JSFIddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/hPh6D/1/)

BTW, IDs and classes cannot start with numbers...hence

**HTML**  (partial)

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <p id="menus">
        <a class="menusor" href="#1">1</a>
        |
        <a class="menusor" href="#2">2</a>
        </p>
    </nav>
</div>
<div id="one"> etc...
```

**CSS** (partial)

```
nav {
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#351b0e;
    width:70%;
    font-size:1.2em;
    padding-left:15%;
    padding-right:15%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0%;
    z-index:9999;
    margin-bottom:25%;
}

#one {
    padding-top:70px; (or some other value)
}
```